How to call Ajax server-side scripts with ajax in devextreme and PHP
i want use DevExtreme tools in my PHP project. But when i use the DevExtreme-PHP-Data example of Devexpress some of the functions don't work.
What I got so far is:
I am using the DevExtreme sample (link) but when processing the data, sorting and filtering there is a lot of errors from the PHP example.
the service.php sample page :
service.php (link)
DataController.php (link)
Somehow the PHP script does work, but when processsing with the dxDataGrid I got a lot of errors.
Like this example (when tyring to sort on the column) :

I found a good example from frostushaer on github but this example also do not use the Server-Side ajax page.
Can't find a great complete PHP ajax sample out there.
How do I use in this sample of DevExtreme extra WHERE statements in the DataController?
How do I setup another example for updating data?
<?php
require_once("../../DevExtreme/LoadHelper.php");
spl_autoload_register(array("DevExtreme\LoadHelper", "LoadModule"));

use DevExtreme\DbSet;
use DevExtreme\DataSourceLoader;

class DataController {
    private $dbSet;
    public function __construct() {
        //TODO: use your database credentials
        $mySQL = new mysqli("serverName", "userName", "password", "databaseName");
        $this->dbSet = new DbSet($mySQL, "tableName");
    }
    public function FillDbIfEmpty() {
        if ($this->dbSet->GetCount() == 0) {
            $curDateString = "2013-1-1";
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
                $curDT = new DateTime($curDateString);
                $curDT->add(new DateInterval("P".strval(rand(1, 1500))."D"));
                $item = array(
                    "Name" => "Name_".strval(rand(1, 100)),
                    "Category" => "Category_".strval(rand(1, 30)),
                    "CustomerName" => "Customer_".strval(rand(1, 50)),
                    "BDate" => $curDT->format("Y-m-d")
                );
                $this->dbSet->Insert($item);
            }
        }
    }
    public function Get($params) {
        $result = DataSourceLoader::Load($this->dbSet, $params);
        if (!isset($result)) {
            $result = $this->dbSet->GetLastError();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function Post($values) {
        $result = $this->dbSet->Insert($values);
        if (!isset($result)) {
            $result = $this->dbSet->GetLastError();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function Put($key, $values) {
        $result = NULL;
        if (isset($key) && isset($values) && is_array($values)) {
            if (!is_array($key)) {
                $keyVal = $key;
                $key = array();
                $key["ID"] = $keyVal;
            }
            $result = $this->dbSet->Update($key, $values);
            if (!isset($result)) {
                $result = $this->dbSet->GetLastError();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exeption("Invalid params");
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function Delete($key) {
        $result = NULL;
        if (isset($key)) {
            if (!is_array($key)) {
                $keyVal = $key;
                $key = array();
                $key["ID"] = $keyVal;
            }
            $result = $this->dbSet->Delete($key);
            if (!isset($result)) {
                $result = $this->dbSet->GetLastError();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exeption("Invalid params");
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - Also please consider a better title for your question, just spamming tags doesn't make it a good title - [ask]

Sorry not my intention to spam, but could not figure a good title.
